# How to stop displaying message from Toast when Application is closed?

Tags: android, toast

This is my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonClick;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Here is the Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When ever I click on the Button, the Toast message is displayed. That's fine.

**My question is:**

When I click *`multiple times`* on the button and then close the **application**, then the **Toasts** continue starting their work of displaying messages.

And I don't want that.

**I want if the application is closed then Toasts should also stop displaying their messages.**

Can anybody tell me what I have to do for this???

Comment: you may do this when closing the app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395062/how-to-cancel-toast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android cancel Toast when exiting the app and when toast is being shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want if the application is closed then Toast should also stop displaying the message.

In your case call `cancel()` to `Toast` object to cancel it within `onDestroy()` method.

Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4395089/646806) example.

**Updated!**

I tested OP solution but no result.

`.hide()` and `.cancel()` method is available for `Toast` but seem they are not working. The solution is, you have to create your own custom view which acts like a `Toast` and then you can cancel all `Toasts` when the `Activity` finishes.

Comment: Is it necessary to create custom view to cancel the Toast only. It seems not a good option as I think.

Comment: You don't have any other option.

Comment: @RobinHood Your first answer was correct so +1. You can `.cancel()` a `Toast` as can be seen in related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown). Code works great, been in production for years.

Answer (score 4):

Store a reference to your toast object.  In your onDestroy, if the toast is not null then call cancel() on it.

Comment: How can I store the reference of Toast object. Toast is static. I am not able to understand it

Comment: No it isn't.  Toast.makeText returns an instance of type Toast.  Save it.  That's what you need to cancel.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to cancel the Toast whenever your app is not visible, so I would cancel it on the method 'onStop()'.

Here it goes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Toast toast = null;
    Button buttonClick;

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                toast.setText("My toast!");
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        toast.cancel();
    }

}
```

Edit: **Updated**, it should work as OP intended now.

Comment: You are testing pressing many times a button and then changing app? This saves the reference to the last Toast so that it cancels the last one. Perhaps you want to cancel previous toasts if they were still visible so that they dont keep stacking

Comment: that the point! OP wants to cancel all toast when activity get closed not only the last one.

Comment: Well it should work now, but the toasts dont stack when the app is running. Most people would expect this behaviour anyway.

Comment: Tested your updated answered its behave weird! its keep cancel first time but after few minutes it start showing, test your code, you will come to know exactly whats the outcomes of your code.

Comment: Explain what you mean please.

Comment: Ok, I corrected it. You were right, I'm sorry. I tested the new version on a very similar code and it works fine.

Comment: Also, you are right about the methods hide and cancel not working as we would expect, that's why I'm using setText.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can cancel `Toast` showing using this code.

```
  final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This message will    disappear     in half second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           toast.cancel(); 
       }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `finish()` in your `OnCreate()` function on some condition. Hope this will help you.