# Asynctask onPostExecute calling after activity finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created an `Asynctask` and started it in an activity, I have shown a toast in `onPostExecute` before completing asynctask I call `finish()` activity but the toast is still showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop displaying message from Toast when Application is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806651/how-to-stop-displaying-message-from-toast-when-application-is-closed)

Comment: You can use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` to show it for a shorter period of time, assuming you use `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Please write some code.

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: Are you calling finish() method before the AsyncTask is completed? If so, you need to cancel your AsyncTask first.

Comment: You can use weak reference to the activity's view (any view) in asynctask, it will be null when activity finishes. if this view's weak reference turns out to be null, don't show toast. (this code is to be done in AsyncTask)

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

you might find this link useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"Toasttext",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

Then you can cancel all the Toast by calling

```
t.cancel();
```