# how to stop display toast before the app close/keyboard open (without overlapping the keyboard layout and the home page)

Tags: android, keyboard, toast, android-toast

Just to clarify what I am asking: I am already closing the toast when call OnStop()/OnPause()/Edit Text OnClick(). Despite the title looks like, this isn't a duplicate of: [How to stop displaying message from Toast when Application is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806651/how-to-stop-displaying-message-from-toast-when-application-is-closed) (sorry, I couldn't found I better title)

So I'm not asking how to close the toast, but how can I update the toast closed before finish the app.

Just to give an example, the alarm clock native of my nexus 5 (4.4.4) shows a notification when you delete an alarm setted. If when close/minimize the app, it close the toast, then close/minimize the app. I would know a code that allow me to do like that.

This is my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private Toast toast;
        private Button buttonClick;
        private EditText editTextClick;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
            editTextClick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextClick);

            buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (toast != null) {
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This might close before the app stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });


             editTextClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This might close before the keyboard open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    if (toast != null) {
                         toast.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }

            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();      // This close toast when stop called 
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

    }
```

I am trying to close a the toast notification ever time the edit text is clicked. But it first open the keyboard (overlapping the toast and keyboard for a while) than close the toast.

The same happen when I close the app or alternate app. The toast disappear after overlapping the other layout.

I have already try to use a `Thread.sleep(1000);` (within a try-catch clause) and after `if(toast != null) { toast.cancel(); }`, but doesn't change anything.

What I could do in this sample code to make it closes the toast then do others things (like open the keyboard, close the app, show recent apps, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not intended to do it, the Toast are designed a way they will just simply disappear after the time given.

What you might do is set the Toast duration to zero on the events you want it to close, but be careful since cero will be like setting LENGTH_SHORT, you may have to override the possible values, they should be miliseconds.

try initializing your toast OUTSIDE your onclick listeners, that may get your onStop and onPause cancels to work, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17740590/3657704